# Are all lone pairs considered as π-electrons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrons

[image: 2‐methylidene‐2H‐pyran]

According to me, in methylenepyran 8 π-electrons are present as there are 3 double bonds. Therefore, 2 × 3 = 6 π-electrons and 2 π-electrons as one of the two lone pairs of oxygen will participate in resonance.

But the correct answer is 10 π-electrons. How? Are both lone pairs of oxygen are being considered? If yes, then why?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine, and 10 is nonsense.

Comment: I thought the same.

Comment: Can you quote the question statement along with options, or link the source, saying the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quoting from http://www.hutters-online.de/publikationen/dmchdo.html.

> One requirement that is basic to this concept and is agreed upon by most authors is that there have to be two double bonds that are in conjugation with a third one, but not in a linear arrangement. The p electronic system thus forms a bifurcation. So the simplest cross-conjugated hydrocarbon would be 3-methylene-1,4-pentadiene (I) that can be viewed as an ethene disubstituted geminally with two vinyl groups:[image: cross conjugation]

Based on the above the following resonance structures are possible. These have 8 $\pi$ electrons in conjugation. You are correct.

[image: resonance structures]